# Can i get my horse into a boat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since 1.9, boats can supposedly transport two entities... I can not for the life of me get my horse into the boat.

Can it be done? 
If yes how? What about a donkey?
If not, which animals can be transported, which can not?

Answer (score 6):

You can get both inside.

1. Find/breed a baby horse/donkey
2. Push it into the boat
3. Stuff it with apples to grow
4. Tame it
5. Put a chest and/or a saddle on it
6. Enjoy your ride!

Comment: This is the only way that would work. The bounty says none of the methods involving adult horses work, which is because it's not possible in pure vanilla survival.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you use a lead to tie your horse and ride the boat like in this picture:[image: Me and my horse sailing off]

**Don't worry about the lead, as long as you are in the boat.**

*I don't want to give out misinformation as I don't have any proof that Mojang intentionally removed mobs entering boats, so I've removed the update section of this answer.*

[Additional proof that this is, in fact, replicable in 1.16+](https://youtu.be/Yp8v-boghQE)

Answer (score 0):

Get them close to the boat and walk into them repeatedly to 'push' them towards it. It might be easier if you use a lead on them and guide them directly into it, though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in 1.13

Comment: Adult horses can't be put in boats or minecarts.

Answer (score 0):

Make the boat stuck so it doesn’t move then push it into the boat. Best if you trap boat in a 2x2 and walk onto the boat with the lead to the other side of where the horse is to lead it in.